# MvcGrid Checkbox with Textbox not showing the right textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

I had a scenario:

My MVCGrid View Image:

[image]

This my Html Javascript Code:

```
 $('#btn_preview_').click(function(){
            Validate()
        });

        function Validate()
        {

            $('.mvcGrid table tr').each(function () {
                if($('.mvcGrid table tr input[name=MyCheckbox]:checkbox').is(':checked')==true)
                {
                    var getText =   $.trim($('.mvcGrid table tr td:eq(2) input[name=textboxRemarks]').val());

                    alert('SID ' + $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() +  ' getText ' + getText);
                }
                else
                {
                    Alert('Checkbox is unchecked');
                }
            });
        }
```

Addtional html code:

```
<div class="mvcGrid rowMarginTop">
               @Html.Grid(Model.myData).Columns(columns =>
               {

                   columns.Add(a => a.isF).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(a=>Html.CheckBox("MyCheckbox",a.isF)).Titled("");
                   columns.Add(a => a.SID).Titled("SID");
                   columns.Add(a => a.Remarks).Titled("Remarks").Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(a => Html.TextBox("textboxRemarks", a.Rem));

               }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true).Filterable()
             </div>
```

All i need to do is to validate if checkbox is checked and the remarks is not empty.

This javascript code is working but my problem is even in `SID 02` the remarks is showing instead of empty.

My Question is how to get the right value of each textbox row?

Any suggestion is pretty much appreciated.

Comment: Please include your html too.

Comment: Thanks @Sumesh TG this is just working only  one MVC Grid, one  button. The only issue is i can't get the right value of a textbox.

Comment: `$(this).parent().find('text box id or class ');` Apply this logic in  checkbox event

Comment: I am calling this `Html.TextBox("textboxRemarks",` textbox name

Comment: Thanks @Sumesh TG my problem is here `$.trim($('.mvcGrid table tr td:eq(2) input[name=textboxRemarks]').val());` it always showing the first row textbox value.

Comment: Are you able to write click event on check box?

Comment: No i just need to validate when button has been click.

Comment: `$('.mvcGrid table tr').each(function (index,item) {` The `$.each` have index paramer use it for read data from row wise.

Comment: Can you show some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btn_preview_').click(function(){
            Validate()
        });

        function Validate()
        {

            $('.mvcGrid table tr').each(function (index,item) {
                if($(this).find(' input[name=MyCheckbox]:checkbox').is(':checked')==true)
                {
                    var getText =   $.trim($(this).find(' input[name=textboxRemarks]').val());

                    alert('SID ' + $(this).find('td:eq('+index+')').text() +  ' getText ' + getText);
                }
                else
                {
                    Alert('Checkbox is unchecked');
                }
            });
        }
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks for this let me try.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Welcome, Let me know if you face any issue again.

Comment: The code has stopped to `$.trim($(this).find(' input[name=textboxRemarks]').val()); my offtime for now. I will review it tommorow. Thanks
`

Comment: @VijunavVastivch Ok, Apply your logic with `index` parameter,